# Dynamically created textboxes don't work with $_POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

For a voting system people see 3 textboxes. But they can add textboxes manually in case they want to vote for more artists. But those textboxes are dynamically created via Javascript using this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var counter = 4;
    $("#addButton").click(function () {


        var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
            .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

        newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Textbox #'+ counter + ' : </label>' +
                                   '<input type="text" name="textbox[]" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" style="width:630px; height:30px; font-size:18px; opacity:0.9;" runat=server>');

        newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
        counter++;
        if(counter==11){
            document.getElementById('addButton').style.visibility='hidden';
            document.getElementById('resetButton').style.position="absolute";
            document.getElementById('resetButton').style.left="60px";
            return false;
        } 
    });

    $("#removeButton").click(function () {
        if(counter==1){
            alert("No more textbox to remove");
            return false;
        }   

        counter--;

        $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();

    });

    $("#getButtonValue").click(function () {

        var msg = '';
        for(i=1; i<counter; i++){
            msg += "\n Textbox #" + i + " : " + $('#textbox' + i).val();
        }
        alert(msg);
    });
});
```

The form where those textboxes spawn in redirects to 'confirm.php' but in confirm.php I can't get the values from the dynamically created textboxes.

How tot fix this?

Comment: "runat=server" - Did you grab that from some .NET source code?

Comment: ^ this, I think you should remove that attribute or make it runat="server", and, just to make it simpler, create a class for style="width:630px; height:30px; font-size:18px; opacity:0.9;" instead of having the whole inline css.

Comment: There's no good reason why the dynamic textboxes won't post properly. Are you using normal form submission or AJAX? Are you accesing `$_POST['textbox']` as an array?

Comment: BTW, you should either wrap the `<label>` element around the input, or use the `for` attribute to link it to the input box.

Comment: @Barmar The first three boxes which are static work perfectly but with the exact same settings the dynamically boxes won't work. (Basic Submission and proper use of array)

Comment: Can you make a fiddle showing what you're doing? There must be some difference between the static elements and the dynamic ones.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to change your code into the following one as I'm wondering if there is something wrong with JQuery:

http://jsfiddle.net/jbLZH/

BTW, the `after()` method in `newTextBoxDiv.after().html` is utterly useless.

Hope this can help.

Answer (score -2):

The textboxes will need the "name" property defined.

Comment: He does that: `name="textbox[]"`

Comment: textbox[] is valid as a name? I didn't think so.

Comment: Definitely. It's used all the time, PHP (and others scripting languages, I presume) automatically collects all the parameters with this name into an array.